# how to compile a latex file containing only a table and references inside the table

Tags: longtable

I have a latex file (supplement.tex) with only a table in it. This table is a supplement to a paper, and I need to use references inside this table. The complete list of references are already listed in original paper (doc.tex). In the end of the supplement.tex I have added the reference file name, so the references can be compiled. Please note that I do not need the list of references at the end of supplement file. I just want the references given in the table are compiled correctly. The table looks like this:

```
\begin{center}
\end{center}
\begin{longtable}{|c | p{4cm}  |p{8cm}|} % centered columns (4 columns)
\caption{The list }
\label{cee}\\
\hline
T & kd & d \\ \hline
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{B}}
 & ne, 
nel & n  \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & g & G .   \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & o &  Oli. \\ \cline{2-3} 
 & der &  Dndi  and .  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 &  ayptic &  Synon.  \\  \cline{2-3} 
& dente & it and spal . \\
 \cline{2-3} 
 & ber, t &  Imports.  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & bn,  &  Bn.  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & mile &  mim.   \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & sd &  The c.  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & gc & Gam   \\  \cline{2-3} 
 &  cer,m &  cere   \\  \cline{2-3}
 & prepulse inhibition & \\  \cline{2-3}
 & Myelin&Mye ne \\  \cline{2-3} 
  & astte & kk)  \\  \cline{2-3} 
 & olfaulb & Olfact  \\  \cline{2-3} 
& ephriceptor & -  \\  \cline{2-3} 
& dmine &  a  mov \\  \cline{2-3} 
& anesis,  & -   \\  \cline{2-3} 
&  myelion & Myel a diels th.   \\  \cline{2-3} 
& osteast  & -   \\  

 \hline 

 \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Mu}}  & sarcre  &   are formed of .   \\ \cline{2-3} 
   &  mus & - \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &  MAP & MAP (mi is one of t  \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &   fusionion & Myob  .   \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &  crein & Sing ce which occurs in      \\ \cline{2-3} 
  &gyogen&\\ \cline{2-3} 
 &cagen &\\
   \hline 

  \multirow{7}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{help}}  & Tell & -   \\ \cline{2-3} 
    &  maroge & Macps are  of  \\ \cline{2-3} 
     &  class II &   class  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& MyD88 & -  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& tolike  & Toll-ills .  \\ \cline{2-3} 
&  class I&HC class I molx () \\  \cline{2-3} 
&   (TNF)& Most mlls\\  

\hline

\multirow{27}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Imem}}
& phagis& Phates. \\ \cline{2-3} 
& erythrtes& -  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& cl& -  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& porphn& One of the kno  \\  \cline{2-3} 
&heme bsyss& Heme  and  \\ \cline{2-3} 
& tolliktor& Toll-lv.   \\ \cline{2-3}

& boalization & \\ \cline{2-3}
& dponse&\\ \cline{2-3}
& lipcharide&Lipopolys.\\ \cline{2-3}
&phagme&In cellosis\\ \cline{2-3}
&  with host&-\\ \cline{2-3}
&  response&-\\ \cline{2-3}
&antigen&In , an ant. \\ \cline{2-3}
& Interferons&Inteor cells.\\ \cline{2-3}
& 
Supide&Superox. \\ \cline{2-3}
&  cedhesion&Interns bm also neith ea,.\\ \cline{2-3}
&  neuil&Neutr acroorganisms.\\ \cline{2-3}
& inrin& Igrins pl.\\ \cline{2-3}

 &Chemotactic & Chegions wit\\ \cline{2-3}
& Macges&Macrophages stim.\\ \cline{2-3}
& Dendrcells &Dendrders. \\ \cline{2-3}
&intein&Interleukins  cells (les).\\ \cline{2-3}
&cytokine&They are pa.\\ \cline{2-3}
& acute-phase response&Positive system.\\ \cline{2-3} 
&negative regula&\\ \cline{2-3} 
&thymus&The thymus is a s.\\ \cline{2-3} 
&chemotactic&\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{he}}  & aant & adregctions   \\ \cline{2-3} 
& het & -  \\ \cline{2-3} 

& carac & -   \\ 
  \hline 

\end{longtable}
\bibliographystyle{natbib}
\bibliography{document.bib}
```

I used

```
 pdflatex '\documentclass{article}\usepackage{longtable}\begin{document}\input{supplement}\end{document}'
```

to compile.

I get the error in line 8

```
<recently read> \multirow                                                                                                                                  

l.8 \multirow
             {17}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{B}}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: unrelated but longtable has not got a `[h]` option.

Comment: The error occurs because you're missing a `\usepackage{longtable}` in the `pdflatex` line. The other solution uses a built-in `table` environment, and doesn't require any extra packages.

Comment: @MikeRenfro Thanks. That solved the problem. Now I get this error: ! Misplaced \noalign.                                                                                                                                      
\hline ->\noalign

Comment: Now you have a different problem: that this table, standalone or not, can't compile. Which `\hline` can you comment out to make the error go away?

Comment: the `\hline` after `\cline` is an error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle removed that. Still get the same error.

Comment: It is impossible to help unless you fix your example so that _reproduces the error_  for which  you are asking for help, add `\documentclass` `\begin{document}` and any packages needed so that the example is a complete small document.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks David for your answer. I will update it now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I put my whole table and the command I use to compile. I appreciate if you have a look.

Comment: @Pegah It's still very unclear: I see no `\cite` command.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I removed all the cite because you do not have my bib file. should I add them?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I updated the code. The number of rows were wrong in the line multirow

Comment: You only showed half the error message, the error is `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \multirow ` the command is undefined as you have not loaded the multirow package. Why don't you make a small document that loads all the needed packages and then inputs supplement.tex rather than doing it all on the commandline?

Comment: if you add `multirow` package you get `! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \rotatebox `   as `graphicx` is not loaded, and so it goes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have undefined commands as the required packages are not loaded.

You could use

```
$  pdflatex '\documentclass{article}\usepackage{longtable,multirow,graphicx}\begin{document}\input{supplement}\end{document}'
```

but more normal would be to use

```
pdflatex supplement-only
```

where `supplement-only.tex` is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{supplement}
\end{document}
```

That way you don't have to keep remembering to construct an increasingly long commandline.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. It solved the problem. The last thing is that instead of references a ? appears. I put the current code to compile in next comment. The supplement file is still the same. Do you have any idea how to solve it? thanks again.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage[square, numbers, comma, sort&compress]{natbib}  
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}\begin{document}
\input{supplement}\end{document}